# Weird line indentation in pgadmin4 query tool, how to fix?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have a very weird indentation in pgAdmin4 and have no idea how to fix it since I find nothing regarding this issue here on SO, neither in the docs or in pgadmin settings.

It basically just puts next line in the middle of the page for no reason. I reinstalled it, but no help.

screenshot: http://prntscr.com/miqdkb

Comment: Closed so I can't add an answer. This was bothering me as well, but I noticed that the unwanted indentation was only happening in the bottom part of my sql file (a file with many different queries). I realized that I had one query that did not have a closed parenthesis. Once I closed it, the editor behaved normally again.